# Join tables from multiple remote database

Tags: mysql, ruby, postgresql, elasticsearch

I have a mysql database on server A, a postgres database on server B and another mysql database on server C. I need a way to join tables from the three servers to get a combined result. Is there a way to do this in ruby ? If not ruby any other language will also suffice.

I need to join somewhere around a few 1000 rows of data. The joined data needs to get pushed to elasticsearch. I was going to use the _bulk api in elasticsearch to push it.

Comment: Can you tell us how many rows/MB of data you want to join ? What do you want to do with all that joined data ?

Comment: Don't know if this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949191/joining-tables-from-postgres-to-mysql-using-mysql-fdw-or But you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a one-off, just download the data from two of the DBs and upload it to the third. Do your work there.

If it's a regular thing it might be worthwhile putting the effort into linking the databases properly. PostgreSQL offers [Foreign Data Wrapper](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) plugins that let you talk to a different database (PostgreSQL or others). One is the [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw).

You define entries for each remote server, user mappings between local user and the remote user, and then describe each table to access. After that you can treat them as local (although performance will generally be much worse of course).

In theory you could write your own fdw plugin to link to elasticsearch too but there doesn't seem to be one currently available.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by LINQ and Entity Framework in Microsoft .Net